Display Order Note to WooCommerce customer email even with Local Pickup shipping method
I have a problem where if a customer chooses Local Pickup shipping method, then the shipping address is not shown, even if they fill it. That is where an order note (optional) can be added.
With Always display shipping address in WooCommerce email notifications answer code
I was able to display the shipping address.
But as the Order NOTE was not included (before I used this code) and ONLY if a Shipping class was used, the order note was NOT included in that order email either.
SO in summary: 
I want the shipping information to ALWAYS be on the order email, regardless of the chosen shipping method, AND I want the order Note to be included too.
The code I use does add the shipping information, but WooCommerce does not include the Order Note as part of the order email, so if I remove the code and place an order with a shipping class, I get the shipping address details, BUT not the Order note. If Local Pickup is the chosen shipping method, then WooCommerce does not provide the shipping address details at all. So the code adds the shipping address details to the order email.

This is all now resolved
the Order note , is in a table and not where i expected to see it , which was in the addresses section
i did try to update earlier , but it keep giving me errors

Is this a working answer to your question? If it's not the case, please delete it and add it as an edit in your question. If it's the case, try to be more explicit, as this answer is actually unclear. As a new user, you should take the quick visual tour that explains things basically.
